# How do I make fetch() ignore net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID from a VSCode extension webview?

Tags: visual-studio-code, https, webview, fetch-api, vscode-extensions

How can I ask VSCode to ignore `net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` when executing fetch() from a webview? I tried setting these settings to false, but it still doesn't work:

```
"http.proxyStrictSSL": false,
"http.systemCertificates": false
```

[image]

Comment: Please keep in mind that none of the questions similar to this one in stack overflow answer my question because either they don't apply to vscode webviews or other questions dont even have any answer.

Comment: why add a comment when you can edit your question

Comment: what if you add a catch handler to the Promise (fetch)

Comment: @rioV8 What am I supposed to do in the catch handler? How do I get the data I request from there?

Comment: you do not handle the error in the promise so the exception is transferred upstream, you will not get the data because you have an error